# How do I allow my post to update it's date every week

Tags: posts

I'm using the Eventure theme for WordPress and I'm trying to make my posts recur. I want it so that I can add a post with it's date, where I can set the iterations where the post is updated. I don't wan't the content of the post to change, I just want the post's date to be updates every iteration. I've looked for plugins but just can't find any that work with the latest version of WordPress. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cron-jobs and there's 2 ways you can do that:

1. `wp_schedule_event($timestamp, $recurrence, $hook, $args);`
    http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event

   The action will trigger when someone visits your WordPress site, if the  scheduled time has passed.
2. Server cron job